# Alternatives to, or fix for, LMERConvenienceFunctions, for use with LME4?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, fitting

Recently I updated from R version 3.6 to version 4.0 for my analyses, and noticed that LMERConvenienceFunctions stopped working. Specifically, I use it in conjunction with LME4.

Whenever I try to use the bfFixefLMER_F.fnc (backfitting of fixed effects in LMER models) or pamer.fnc (compute upper- and lower-bound p-values for the analysis of variance or deviance) for a LMER model fitted through LME4, regardless of dataset, I am met with the error  "Error in pf(anova.table[term, "F value"], anova.table[term, "Df"], nrow(model@frame) - : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function". I have tried this on two separate computers with the same result. Now, as far as I can tell, LMERConvenienceFunctions hasn't been updated since 2015, so I'm not holding out hope that a fix is forthcoming.

I tried reverting to R 3.6.2, but found the same error using the versions of LME4 that were out shortly before R 4.0 came out. I have finally found the previous version I was using, so this will (hopefully) fix it for my current analysis, but doesn't help if I want to use the most recent version of R and LME4 going forwards.

Other functions of LMERConvenience (namely fitLMER.fnc and mcp.fnc) seem to be working properly, so it doesn't seem to be a systematic issue, but it is definitely one that significantly impedes my work.

Does anyone have any suggestions for alternative packages, a link to old versions of LME4, or could anyone offer any advice on editing the LMERConvenienceFunctions package so that I can get the broken functions working again? I don't have any experience with changing the coding within packages, so would be starting from bare basics there.

Edit: I am also aware that there are some workarounds through adding extra code in my R script, as I did find in my searching for an answer that it had previously been a problem with the same package in 2014 (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2014q2/022264.html), but I am not familiar with writing that kind of code, so would appreciate any guidance there as well.

Edit 2: As suggested, I have crossposted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988764/r-alternatives-to-or-fix-for-lmerconveniencefunctions-for-use-with-lme4

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about statistics, but rather coding. You might have more luck on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok; I will try crossposting it there. I thought that this might be the better forum as the focus is statistical, so the likelihood of someone having direct experience might be higher, but I can definitely see the benefit of posting in both places